# Error using regular expressions in DB2 - wrong syntax?

Tags: db2

i tried to run this query in DB2 ( which includes regex ). I am getting the following error. Can someone help?

Here is the query:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(FIELD), '[^[:digit:]]')
[image]

Comment: Are you running an old version of db2 where REGEXP_LIKE is not supported? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html

Comment: i have version 11.1 - does not that version support regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in DB2 using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766117/error-in-db2-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Support for `BOOLEAN` data type is new in Db2 11.1.1.1  (i.e. the first Mod Pack + Fix pack for Db2 11.1). If you are only on Db2 11.1.0.0, then you will need to explicitly test the result of your regex function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(FIELD), '[^[:digit:]]') = 1;
```